# show elements on touch event of iPad

Tags: ipad, touch

I need a function to show some action items in each row of a grid when user tap/ touch the row. As shown in image attached. At one time only one rows action items should be visible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Era
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using UITableView only right. Then you can simply get the index of that row and can change the cell for that index.